# Handlers in MAUI is working only in sample project. The Constructor or CreatePlatformView or ConnectHandler from handler class is not getting called

Tags: custom-controls, maui, handler

An iOS app was created using Xamarin Forms(The app is only for iOS). The Xamarin project has CustomRenderer for displaying Context menu. It looks as you can see in the below image[image]

After upgrading to MAUI, I tried to reuse the same CustomRenderer.
It is not showing the context menu in MAUI project. And It is not even calling OnElementChanged method when using the CustomRenderer.

I decided to create a handler for the same. It is also not showing the context menu. Even the Constructor or CreatePlatformView or ConnectHandler from handler class is not getting called.
I'm not sure what is wrong.

The handler code is explained below.

In MauiProgram class, I've registered Handler with the following line:

```
handlers.AddHandler(typeof(ContextMenuView), typeof(ContextMenuViewHandler));
```

The custom control in defined as follows:

```
    public class ContextMenuView : View
    {
        public MenuRequested MenuRequested;

        public void RequestMenu(object sender, double x, double y, double width, double height)
        {
            MenuRequested?.Invoke(sender, new MenuRequestedEventArgs(x, y, width, height));
        }

        public bool CanCut { get; set; } = true;
        public bool CanCopy { get; set; } = true;
        public bool CanDelete { get; set; } = true;
        public bool HasProperties { get; set; } = true;

        public Action OnCopy { get; set; }
        public Action OnDelete { get; set; }
        public Action OnProperties { get; set; }
        public Action OnCut { get; set; }

        public IContextCommand[] Commands { get; set; }
    }
```

The handler is defined as follows:

```
    public class ContextMenuViewHandler : ViewHandler<ContextMenuView, ContextMenuiOS>
    {
        private nfloat _height;
        private nfloat _width;

        string ACTION_PREFIX = "custom_action";
        int MAX_CUSTOM_ACTIONS = 4;

        public static IPropertyMapper<ContextMenuView, ContextMenuViewHandler> PropertyMapper =
            new PropertyMapper<ContextMenuView, ContextMenuViewHandler>(ViewHandler.ViewMapper)
            {

            };

        public ContextMenuViewHandler() : base(PropertyMapper)
        {
        }

        protected override ContextMenuiOS CreatePlatformView()
        {
            return new ContextMenuiOS(VirtualView);
        }

        protected override void ConnectHandler(ContextMenuiOS platformView)
        {
            base.ConnectHandler(platformView);

            VirtualView.MenuRequested += OnMenuRequested;
        }

        protected override void DisconnectHandler(ContextMenuiOS platformView)
        {
            base.DisconnectHandler(platformView);

            VirtualView.MenuRequested -= OnMenuRequested;
        }

        private void OnMenuRequested(object _, MenuRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var _menu = UIMenuController.SharedMenuController;
                PlatformView.BecomeFirstResponder();
                var items = new List<UIMenuItem>();
                if (VirtualView.Commands?.Any() == true)
                {
                    var index = 0;
                    foreach (var item in VirtualView.Commands.Where(o => o.Command.CanExecute(null)).Take(MAX_CUSTOM_ACTIONS))
                    {
                        items.Add(new UIMenuItem
                        {
                            Title = item.Name,
                            Action = new Selector($"{ACTION_PREFIX}{index++}:")
                        });
                    }
                }
                if (VirtualView.HasProperties)
                {
                    items.Add(new UIMenuItem("Options...", new Selector("Properties:")));
                }
                _menu.MenuItems = items.ToArray();
                _menu.SetTargetRect(new CGRect(e.X, e.Y, e.Width, e.Height), PlatformView);
                _menu.MenuVisible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

ContextMenuiOS is defined as follows:

```
    public class ContextMenuiOS : UIView
    {
        private nfloat _height;
        private nfloat _width;

        const string ACTION_PREFIX = "custom_action";
        const int MAX_CUSTOM_ACTIONS = 4;

        ContextMenuView Mauiview;

        public ContextMenuiOS(ContextMenuView view)
        {
            Mauiview = view;

            _height = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
            _width = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
            Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, _width, _height);
        }

        public override bool CanBecomeFirstResponder => true;

        public override bool CanPerform(Selector action, NSObject withSender)
        {
            switch (action.Name)
            {
                case "Properties:":
                    return Mauiview.HasProperties;
                case "cut:":
                    return Mauiview.CanCut;
                case "copy:":
                    return Mauiview.CanCopy;
                case "delete:":
                    return Mauiview.CanDelete;
            }
            if (action.Name.StartsWith(ACTION_PREFIX))
            {
                var indexString = action.Name.Substring(ACTION_PREFIX.Length, action.Name.Length - ACTION_PREFIX.Length - 1);
                var index = int.Parse(indexString);
                return Mauiview.Commands[index].Command.CanExecute(null);
            }
            return true;
        }

        [Export("Properties:")]
        public void Properties(UIMenuController controller)
        {
            Mauiview?.OnProperties();
        }

        [Export("custom_action0:")]
        public void Action0(UIMenuController controller)
        {
            Mauiview.Commands[0].Command.Execute(null);
        }

        [Export("custom_action1:")]
        public void Action1(UIMenuController controller)
        {
            Mauiview.Commands[1].Command.Execute(null);
        }

        [Export("custom_action2:")]
        public void Action2(UIMenuController controller)
        {
            Mauiview.Commands[2].Command.Execute(null);
        }

        [Export("custom_action3:")]
        public void Action3(UIMenuController controller)
        {
            Mauiview.Commands[3].Command.Execute(null);
        }

        public override void Cut(NSObject sender)
        {
            Mauiview?.OnCut();
        }

        public override void Copy(NSObject sender)
        {
            Mauiview?.OnCopy();
        }

        public override void Delete(NSObject sender)
        {
            Mauiview?.OnDelete();
        }
    }
```

**Note: I tried to create a sample project to post in GitHub.
But in sample project the same code shows up the context menu.**

The sample project repo can be found with the following link:
https://github.com/apy534/MAUI-Handler-test

**The gitHub project is using CustomRenderer by default. You can switch to Handler from CustomRenderer by changing the registration of Render to handler in MauiProgram class.**

Anyone facing the similar kind of issue?

Comment: In .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI), a context menu can be added on Mac Catalyst and Windows. Did you use it on iOS?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT
I hope you are saying about MenuFlyout. It is not showing up on iOS device

Comment: _"the same is not working when integrated in main project."_ Yes, your sample works well, but what's the meaning of not working? Any error or context not shown or cannot customize? And how you integrated in main project? It's better to include these information in your question.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT

With both the solutions - handler implementation or CustomRenderer reuse, context menu is not showing up  when integrated in the main project. The CustomRenderer/Handler is not hitting at all.

Comment: That's weird. Your sample using handler does work well on my end. I don't know what your main project is like. Is it because the layout difference?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT

Your willingness to lend a hand and go the extra mile truly made a significant difference, and I am incredibly thankful for your support. 
I'm not sure what might be wrong with my layout. Any suggestion on how to trace the issue

Comment: I am not sure as I don't know your project well. How do you invoke the method of showing the Context menu? Could it be sheltered by other control? Or does it execute on MainThread? I am not sure, I was only thinking of such possibilities.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT
I verified again. It is invoked on the main thread. 
The same code is being used as is in my sample project.
The parent is ContentPage

Comment: Which way you use to migration, [.NET Upgrade Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/upgrade-assistant) or [Upgrade manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/forms-projects)?  Could you share a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT
The app is manually upgraded. I'll try to share reproducible example ASAP, if I could reproduce it

Comment: I assume that's due to the migration. Maybe it's hard to reproduce.

Comment: Yes @LiqunShen-MSFT,
I'm unable to reproduce. But trying to figure out the root cause